# I need to run query "USE database", everytime i call a new function

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Every time i call a new function it shows an error that

> "No database is selected".

Previously it was not the case, i only had to call `"USE database"` once.

I have replaced **DriverManager** with **MySqlDataSource.**

I am running `"USE database"` query at the starting of program by calling InitializeData();

```
public class Database {

public static MysqlDataSource dataSource;

static void InitializeData()
{
     dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
     dataSource.setUser("root");
     dataSource.setPassword("zxcvbnm@123");

    try{
    Connection con = Main.getConnection();
    Statement existence = con.createStatement();
    boolean q1 = existence.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS votingdata");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.execute("USE votingdata");
    ...........................................continue.........
```

This is Main.getConnection() function

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection con=null;
    try {
        con = Database.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.print("Connection lost   "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add  a proper setting to you dbname

```
dataSource.setDatabaseName("YOUR_DB__NAME");
```

-

```
static void InitializeData()
{
  dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
  dataSource.setUser("root");
  dataSource.setPassword("zxcvbnm@123");
  dataSource.setDatabaseName("YOUR_DB__NAME"); 


 try{
  .....
```

Comment: This worked. But what was the problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: no  ..is not a bug  .. if you don't assign a proper db name during connection the db engine don't know  which db use  (or better use the default db name  ..  )  in the connection string you should always assign the db name

Comment: But in the function InitializeData() i have used the query " USE votingdata".

Comment: USE don't set the database    is a temporary setting valid for the single query  only  .. so  as  suggested  before  you should always  assign the db name for your woring db in the connection string

Comment: @scaisEdge *`USE` ... is a temporary setting valid for the single query only* ... don't you mean a single *connection* only?  ["The `USE db_name` statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database remains the default until the end of the session or another USE statement is issued."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html)